# beautifulsoup4 keeps printing none

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup

### HTML

```html
<div class="secondary">
            <dl>
                <div><dt>Joined</dt><dd><span class="relative-date date" title="Nov 2, 2019 9:24 pm" data-time="1572701042645" data-format="medium">Nov 2, '19</span></dd></div>
                <div><dt>Last Post</dt><dd><span class="relative-date date" title="Nov 1, 2020 4:21 pm" data-time="1604218868661" data-format="medium">18 hours</span></dd></div>
                <div><dt>Seen</dt><dd><span class="relative-date date" title="Nov 2, 2020 10:38 am" data-time="1604284735243" data-format="medium">12 mins</span></dd></div>
                <div><dt>Views</dt><dd>546</dd></div>
<!---->                <div><dt class="trust-level">Trust Level</dt><dd class="trust-level">Member</dd></div>
<!---->                <div><dt class="groups">Groups</dt>
                <dd class="groups">
                    <span><a href="/g/Programmers" id="ember47" class="group-link ember-view">Programmers</a></span>
                    <span><a href="/g/Web_Developer" id="ember49" class="group-link ember-view">Web_Developer</a></span>

<a href="/g?username=OctaLua" id="ember50" class="ember-view">                    ...
</a>                </dd>
                </div>

<!---->            </dl>
            <span id="ember51" class="ember-view">  <div id="ember53" class="user-profile-secondary-outlet follow-statistics-user ember-view"><!----></div>
</span>
          </div>
```

so I am trying to get the "secondary" class using the Python BeautifulSoup4 Library

```py
page = requests.get('https://devforum.roblox.com/u/octalua').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('div', {'class': 'secondary'})

print(content)
```

but whenever I print the content it keeps printing none even though I defined the class already, if you wish to check the URL its at the python code thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part of the webpage is loaded dynamically, so you have to use `selenium` in order to scrape it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://devforum.roblox.com/u/octalua')
time.sleep(3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

content = soup.find('div', {'class': 'secondary'})

print(content)

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
<div class="secondary">
<dl>
<div><dt>Joined</dt><dd><span class="relative-date date" data-format="medium" data-time="1572701042645" title="Nov 2, 2019 6:54 pm">Nov 2, '19</span></dd></div>
<div><dt>Last Post</dt><dd><span class="relative-date date" data-format="medium" data-time="1604218868661" title="Nov 1, 2020 1:51 pm">19 hours</span></dd></div>
<div><dt>Seen</dt><dd><span class="relative-date date" data-format="medium" data-time="1604284735243" title="Nov 2, 2020 8:08 am">19 mins</span></dd></div>
<div><dt>Views</dt><dd>550</dd></div>
<!-- --> <div><dt class="trust-level">Trust Level</dt><dd class="trust-level">Member</dd></div>
<!-- --> <div><dt class="groups">Groups</dt>
<dd class="groups">
<span><a class="group-link ember-view" href="/g/Programmers" id="ember47">Programmers</a></span>
<span><a class="group-link ember-view" href="/g/Web_Developer" id="ember49">Web_Developer</a></span>
<a class="ember-view" href="/g?username=OctaLua" id="ember50">                    ...
</a> </dd>
</div>
<!-- --> </dl>
<span class="ember-view" id="ember51"> <div class="user-profile-secondary-outlet follow-statistics-user ember-view" id="ember53"><!-- --></div>
</span>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

You can also do the same using the `json` file. Here is the code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

dictt = requests.get('https://devforum.roblox.com/u/octalua/summary.json').json()

lst = dictt['topics']

final = {}

needed_keys = ["id","posts_count","reply_count","last_posted_at"]

for dictionary in lst:
    for key in dictionary.keys():
        if key in needed_keys:
            if set(needed_keys).issubset(dictionary.keys()):
                final.setdefault(key,[]).append(dictionary[key])
            else:
                if key not in dictionary.keys():
                    final.setdefault(key, []).append(float("nan"))

df = pd.DataFrame(final,index=final['id'])
df = df.drop('id', axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        posts_count  reply_count            last_posted_at
777375            5            1  2020-09-19T10:09:30.064Z
571759            9            6  2020-05-14T12:15:38.374Z
626599            9            4  2020-06-15T17:24:31.469Z
610010            4            0  2020-06-04T07:24:15.153Z
593138            2            1  2020-06-01T12:01:21.984Z
548304            4            0  2020-04-29T14:11:44.803Z
830091            2            0  2020-10-21T04:27:50.161Z
606410           25           23  2020-08-14T22:22:59.322Z
612874            7            4  2020-08-29T05:48:49.863Z
841094           11            5  2020-10-28T12:55:10.337Z
841110            7            4  2020-10-29T17:25:40.995Z
419774         4813         1983  2020-11-02T04:31:40.577Z
607078           10            6  2020-06-03T14:35:40.271Z
831553           11            6  2020-10-22T16:07:17.877Z
```

Comment: You'll have to download selenium and it's webdriver*

Comment: Yes. I think that the OP has `selenium` and `chromedriver` installed, cuz he has asked many questions related to `selenium`

Comment: What do you mean its loaded dynamically?

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40206536/12309808

Comment: Not sure if this is how it works but I checked the network and found this https://devforum.roblox.com/u/octalua/summary.json so I assumed I can send a get request to that then convert it to html

Comment: That is another way of doing it. Should I give u a solution using this `json` file?

Comment: What are the details that u wanna extract from the json?

Comment: Post counts, reply counts, last posted. I printed the output and It contained those stuff unfortunately I cant send it since its too long.

Comment: @NobleScripts Did u check out my latest solution that uses `json`? Did it work for u?

Answer (score 0):

This should work since it's loaded dynamically.

```
driver.get('https://devforum.roblox.com/u/octalua')
elem=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "secondary")))
print(elem.text)#or .content
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
```

Outputs

```
Joined
Nov 2, '19
Last Post
19 hours
Seen
26 mins
Views
556
Trust Level
Member
Groups
Programmers Web_Developer ...
```